# Delete incompatible ScreenFlow version from MacOS Sierra

Tags: mac-appstore

- I logged into my iCloud account from a fresh install of macOS Sierra.
- I had a very old version of ScreenFlow (from 2011) under Purchases in the App Store.
- Installing it worked.
- When I try to open it (from the App Store or from Spotlight), it says it's incompatible and offers me to search for a newer version.

Now how do I remove this old installed version? The App Store only shows me an "Open" button under Purchases, but I can't click on the icon to take me to a details page with an option to uninstall it.

It's harmless to just leave it there, but besides taking up a little disk space for nothing, it pollutes the Spotlight search index and just makes me feel my computer a little "dirty".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Removing ScreenFlow from Your Computer](http://www.telestream.net/telestream-support/screen-flow/help/Install.11.6.html)

To uninstall ScreenFlow, simply move the ScreenFlow application to the trash. (The ScreenFlow license is stored separately, so you do not need to re-activate your license if you reinstall ScreenFlow.)
To completely remove ScreenFlow from your computer, move the following files to your trash:

- /Applications/ScreenFlow
- /System/Library/Extensions/TelestreamAudio.kext
- /Library/Preferences/net.telestream.screenflow.plist
- ~/Library/Preferences/com.vara.screenflow.LSSharedFileList.plist
- ~/Library/Preferences/com.vara.screenflow.plist
- ~/Library/Preferences/com.vara.screenflowhelper.plist
- ~/Library/Preferences/net.telestream.screenflowapp.LSSharedFileList.plist
- ~/Library/Preferences/net.telestream.screenflowapp.plist
- ~/Library/Preferences/net.telestream.screenflowhelper.plist